# Sending Optional Parameters In Asynchronous Delegate Calls

Tags: c#, delegates

**Here is my delegate signature:**

```
public delegate PrintAllergyClass AllergiesDelegate(
    long patientAccount, long chartId, bool isCf, string practiceCode = "");
```

**Here is how i call it:**

```
AllergiesDelegate allergies = new AllergiesDelegate(
    GetChartFacadeObj().LoadAllergyPrintData);
IAsyncResult Allergies = allergies.BeginInvoke(
    long.Parse(patientAccount), long.Parse(chartID), Is_CF, null, null);
```

**Here is the function signature:**

```
public PrintAllergyClass LoadAllergyPrintData(
    long PAcc, long ChartID, bool Is_CF, string PracticeCode="")
```

But it gives me error:

> No overload for method 'BeginInvoke' takes 5 arguments.

On intellisense,it shows desired arguments as expected.

Kindly guide me, how to handle this case?

Comment: Look at intellisense to see what allergies.BeginInvoke expects. Then give what it expects.

Comment: Besides the point of the question but you should probably use `Task` instead of the thread-pool based APM model.

Comment: @usr..on intellisense it shows desired arguments,with practiceCode as optional

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense shows you how to call that delegate:

[image]

There are two additional infrastructure arguments that can be supplied. The optional parameter in the delegate signature does not transfer to the delegate's `BeginInvoke` method.

```
    public delegate object AllergiesDelegate(
        long patientAccount, long chartId, bool isCf, string practiceCode = "");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AllergiesDelegate allergies = null;
        IAsyncResult Allergies = allergies.BeginInvoke(0, 0, false, "", null, null);
    }
```

Comment: @usr..i am not able to view the image,can you please elaborate or give me piece of code for that...

Comment: What about `EndInvoke`? You always call `EndInvoke` after `BeginInvoke`, to allow any clean up that is necessary.

Comment: @Aron I agree, but what about it? Just call EndInvoke at any point you like. The question is not about that.

Comment: -1 Now you are a) throwing away the result b) trying to get the result out before the Invocation begins.

Comment: @Aron this is not the point of the question at all. This is demo code. What, in your mind, is the point of the question?

Comment: @usr...thanks...but then what is the benefit of optional if i gonna explicitly pass empty argument???

Comment: @usr It is ambiguous at best. To me, it looks like the OP does not understand APM or delegates, and just wants to invoke the delegate, and accidentally used `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` and just does not understand why its soooo complicated to invoke a delegate. What on earth is `object state` and what is a `CallBack`...

Comment: @Muhammadali the benefit is that it works... What else can I tell you? The APM pattern just does not support optional arguments. Maybe you can add an overload to `LoadAllergyPrintData` that does not have the final string parameter? That way there are no optional parameters.

Comment: @Aron the question title sounds quite descriptive: "Sending Optional Parameters In Asynchronous Delegate Calls". Little room for interpretation there.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help...but i not get ,yet my answer

Comment: @Muhammadali that is not a helpful statement. You need to explain.

Comment: @usr...what i want  is that i have 20+ functions which use delegate async calls,now i want that some of my function demands an additional optional parameter,so kindly tell me how to pass optional parameter to .beginInvoke???